# Bayesian Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian

I started learning about Bayesian Inference, and it's mostly dealing with parameter estimation (i. e. estimating a parameter $\theta$ of a Bernouli Distribution.

I'm wondering if there are any textbook for Bayesian Machine Learning (i.e. Given some training data (X, Y), with a feature vector $X$ learn a function $f$ such that $f(X) = Y $ but with a bayesian perspective.

Comment: Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Still not quite clear to me what *exactly* you want to get out of the book. Bayesian Methods for Hackers is a book hosted on GitHub, might possibly give you what you need, and if not - it's free.

Comment: @nbro Several indeed--there are around 1 million results on google scholar ;)